# Finitely additive vs countably additive

Tags: measure-theory

Given a set $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, and a set function $\mu$ defined on all the subsets of $X$ found in $\mathcal{F}$.

If $\mu$ is said to be *finitely additive*, but you also know it is not *countably additive*, what does that say about the subsets of $\mathcal{F}$? Does it say anything else about $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: I don't think $\mu$ is a measure if it does not satisfy countable additivity.

Comment: @guy3141 I think you're right, I have changed the question to better reflect what I am really asking

Comment: You cannot conclude much: you can have finitely but not countably additive "measures" $\mu$ on $\sigma$-algebras that, simultaneously, admit proper measures.

Comment: I recommend reading about pre-measures defined on an algebra of sets.  These are functions that satisfy finite additivity and when a countable union lies in the algbera they satisfy countable additivity.  Pre-measures give rise to outer measures and from an outer measure a measure is born!  The whole process is rather interesting.

Comment: As @Andrés E. Caicedo said in a comment, you can't really conclude anything about $\mathcal F.$ However, if you're interested in finitely additive "measures" and have access to a university library, see [**Theory of Charges. A Study of Finitely Additive Measures**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/pure-and-applied-mathematics/vol/109) (1983) by K.P.S. Bhaskara Rao and M. Bhaskara Rao (Volume 109 in the well-known *Pure and Applied Mathematics* series published by Academic Press).